Where should the base resistor be placed in a PNP switch?

I would like to understand the difference between placing a base resistor at R2 versus R4 when implementing a PNP switch. It seems there is no difference whether I place a 4.7K resistor at R2 and short R4, or short R2 and place a 4.7K resistor at R4 (both performing the same high side switch function). Can you explain the difference between these two configurations?

You have drewn the circuit in LTSpice simulator. Have you simulated what the difference is?

47k is unnecessarily high for the base shunt resistor. 4.7k would  be better.

@Justme Yes, it works well.

@SpehroPefhany Can you elaborate a little bit? According to this site, I learned that about 10 times the base resistance is suitable. https://www.w9xt.com/page_microdesign_pt8_pnp_switching.html

@BOB_Engineer It depends on the ratio of drive voltage (12V in your case) to 0.7V. With 1:1 you are losing 0.7/12 or less than 6% of the drive current. Why would you want to have it relatively low? The worst-case leakage is only 50nA but with it doubling every 10°C you could have Q2 starting to turn on at (very) high temperatures. For most purposes and typically the 47k will be fine, just that it could be better.

@SpehroPefhany You said that "47k(R3) will be fine". Did you mean to say 4.7k(R3) instead of 47k(R3)? I am asking becuase you mentioned earlier that 47k(R3) seemed too high. Also, could you kindly explain how 50nA leakage current was caculated. Many thanks!

The 50nA @25°C is directly from the transistor datasheet but, as a rule of thumb, it doubles every 10°C. For most purposes 47k will be fine, but somewhat lower would be better. With the given values, the drive current is 11.3V/4.7kΩ = 2.4mA. You are only shunting away 0.7V/47kΩ = 15uA or about 0.6%. You can afford to shunt away 5 or 10%.

Well, you can calculate the equivalent circuits in both cases.
If you short R4, you will have

when Q1 is open: 47k with a 0V driving voltage
when Q1 is closed: 4.3k with a -10.9V driving voltage (roughly 2.37mA base current considering Vbe = 0.7V)

If you short R2 (and put 4.7k as R4), you will have

when Q1 is open: 51.7k with a 0V driving voltage
when Q1 is closed: 4.7k with a -12V driving voltage (roughly 2.4mA base current considering Vbe = 0.7V)

Will they be the same? It depends.
For instance if the whole upper part (12V, Q2) is on a board and the driving part (Q1) on another, it's better to have limitation resistors on the driver part, so it would be better to leave R2 to protect against short circuits (but then to protect Q2 I would also add R4, so...)
Personally I'd go with shorting R4, but probably that's just because I always did it this way. With the 10% larger resistance when turning off the circuit you will have a slower turning off phase, but I don't know if the time scale for this is so short that it can practically affect anything
